# Prove that $col(A^n) + nul(A^n) = \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider a linear transformation such that $A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, is it possible to prove the following identity?
\begin{align}
col(A^n) + nul(A^n) = \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}
I have been struggling on this problem for a week and I appreciate if anyone can point a direction or provide a proof for this.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe this is called the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem). A proof is listed on the page there.

Comment: This is different from the rank-nullify theorem. First it does not concern the dimension of each subspace, but the subspaces themselves. Also the transformation is raised to a power of n. Thank you for your comment anyway!

Comment: $A^n$ is just as much a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ as $A$, so the rank-nullity theorem still applies to it.

Comment: Yes the rank-nullity theorem still applies but the problem I have here is not about their dimensions while the rank-nullity theorem is only concerning the dimension. Note that $col(A) + nul(A) \neq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: By $\mathrm{col}(A^n)$, do you mean $\mathrm{Im}(A^n)$, where $A^n = A \circ \ldots \circ A$ ?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean by that

Comment: Why $col A + nul A \neq \mathbb R^n$?!

Comment: @R.Suwalski. Well, Penthrite probably meant it is not true in general.Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to prove something slightly more general. You might apply the following theorem to $K=\mathbb{R}$, $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u$ the endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ canonically associated to $A$ to get $\ker(A^n)\oplus\mathrm{im}(A^n)=\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Theorem.** Let $K$ be a field, let $E$ be a $K$-vector space of dimension $n\geq 1$, and let $u\in \mathscr{L}(E)$ be an endomorphism of $E$. Then $$\ker(u^n)\oplus \mathrm{im}(u^n)=E.$$

**Proof.**

Let $P\in K[X]$ be the minimal polynomial of $u$, and write $P=X^m Q,$ with $m\geq 0$ and $Q(0)\neq 0$.
Set $N=\ker(u^m)$ and $C=\ker(Q(u))$. Then $N,C$ are stable by $u$, and $$E=N\oplus C,$$ since $X^m$ and $Q$ are coprime polynomials.

Since $N$ and $C$ are stable by $u$, we get by double restriction an endomorphism $u_N$ of $N$, and an endomorphism $u_C$ of $C.$

**Fact.** $u_N$ is nilpotent and $u_C$ is an automorphism of $C$.

Indeed, $X^m$ annihilates $u_N$ by definition, so $u_N$ is nilpotent

Since $Q(0)\neq 0$, we may write $Q=XR+a,$ with $a\neq 0$. Since $Q$ annihilates $u_C$, we get $$0=u_C\circ R(u_C)+aId_C,$$ that is $$ u_C\circ (-a^{-1}R(u_C))=Id_C.$$ Hence $u_C$ is invertible.

By definition of $m$, we have $u_N^m=0$. Since $m\leq n$, we get $u_N^n=0$.

But for all $x\in N$ and $y\in C$ , we have
$$u^n(x+y)=u^n(x)+u^n(y)=u_N^n(x)+u_C^n(y)=u_C^n(y).$$
Since $u_C$ is invertible, so is $u_C^n$. Hence we get $$u^n(x+y)=0\iff u_C^n(y)=0\iff y=0,$$ meaning that $\ker(u^n)=N.$

Moreover, $\mathrm{im}(u^n)=\mathrm{im}(u_C^n)=C,$ since $u_c^n$ is invertible. Consequently, $$E=N\oplus C=\ker(u^n)\oplus\mathrm{im}(u^n).$$

PS. Modifying slightly the proof, one can in fact show that if $X^m$ is the greastest power of $X$ dividing the minimal polynomial of $u$, then for all $k\geq m$, $E=\ker(u^k)\oplus\mathrm{im}(u^k)$.